# ALB route socket connection to the same server

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to horizontally scale my socket application with an application load balancer in front. since it's a room-based application, I want to route all the participants in the same room to the same ECS task instance.
here's a simple flow user1 create a room1 and alb decides to redirect to ecs_task1, then user2 wants to join room1, using id: room1, alb should redirect user2 to the same ecs_task1 so they can be on the same instance.
after some research I find was alb can support some listening rules, and I think path-pattern might be able to work. so my logic is to bind room1 to the id of the task_id of ecs_task1 and using that as the path-pattern. however, then when the socket connection starts, I will need to bind the path using socket.of('<task_id>') and from the server end I will want to ignore the that task_id or listen on some sort of wildcard path right? I can't seem to find a support for wildcard path for socket io to listen on. is that doable?
or steping back a bit, is this a good architecture to handle the socket with room?

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by 'socket application'. It seems you might want to have a look at sticky sessions, which make sure that all requests from an user (single session) are routed to the same backend instance/container.

Comment: @StefanN thanks for the comment! yes, a sticky session can only ensure one user/client route to the same server, but I want to make sure multiple clients/users under same "room" get route to the same server.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, as the first request an ALB receives has no the required cookie (it only get set as a response to the fist request). Therefore there is no way to guarantee where (at which target instance) the first request will end up. However, I am quite confident that you can design your systems, so that it does not require multiple users talking to the same instance. Probably some global store such as DynamoDB can be used to keep the shared sate.